How to configure a Quarkus to expose health endpoints over HTTPS 8443 while requiring mutual TLS (mTLS) for all other endpoints (same port 8443)?
I would like to configure Quarkus to exclude the health endpoint from mutual TLS (mTLS) so that Kubernetes can access it.
Is this possible that you set up a specific "route" in your application configuration to allow unauthenticated access to the health endpoint?
I have configured the application.properties like this:
# Server TLS
quarkus.http.insecure-requests=disabled
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=tls/keystore.p12
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file-type=PKCS12
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-password=123456

# Client certificate authentication
quarkus.http.ssl.client-auth=required
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.trust-store-file=tls/truststore.p12
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.trust-store-password=123456

I have disabled HTTP port 8080 and configured that only the mTLS is possible.
How should I configure/implement so that the health endpoint is reachable without only via TLS not mutual TLS validation.

AFAIK this is not doable as the TLS handshake is done before the URL is analyzed and routed... but you can expose the management API on another port with quarkus.management.enabled=true and quarkus.management.port=someport with or without TLS. That is probably your best bet.

You can configure your application in this way. In this case, using the TLS Registry to configure the HTTPS and the mutual auth via client certs (For more information on the TLS registry, see https://quarkus.io/guides/tls-registry-reference).
If you set the properties quarkus.http.ssl.client-auth to REQUEST, the health endpoint will be properly function.
You can find a complete project at GitHub https://github.com/amusarra/quarkus-mtls-auth/tree/main
#
# Section to configure the server to use HTTPS using the TLS registry,
# which was introduced in Quarkus 3.14 (https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-3-14-1-released/)
# For more information on the TLS registry, see https://quarkus.io/guides/tls-registry-reference
#

# Setting the key-store path. The key-store file is located in the `certs` directory
# inside the resources directory.
quarkus.tls.https.key-store.p12.path=certs/server_cert.p12

# Setting the key-store password.
# The password is stored in the `application.properties` file.
# In a development environment, the password may be changed when regenerating the key-store (e.g., using the `mvn clean` command).
# In a production environment, it is recommended to use a secure password storage mechanism.
quarkus.tls.https.key-store.p12.password=RYF7oOQ1WLVip9jP

# Setting the trust-store path.
# The trust-store file is located in the `certs` directory
# inside the resources directory.
quarkus.tls.https.trust-store.pem.certs=certs/ca_cert.pem,/tmp/tsl-it/tsl-it_bundle.pem

# Disabling insecure requests, only HTTPS requests are allowed.
quarkus.http.insecure-requests=disabled

# Setting the only supported TLS protocol to TLSv1.3.
quarkus.tls.https.protocols=TLSv1.3

# Setting the reload period for the TLS configuration to 125 seconds.
quarkus.tls.https.reload-period=125s

# Setting the TLS configuration name to `https`.
quarkus.http.tls-configuration-name=https

#
# Section to configure the server for mTLS authentication mechanism.
# For more information see Authentication mechanisms in Quarkus https://quarkus.io/guides/tls-registry-reference#mtls
# and configuring mTLS in Quarkus https://quarkus.io/guides/tls-registry-reference#configuring-mtls
#

# Enabling the mTLS authentication mechanism.
# The server requires clients to authenticate themselves using a client certificate.
# The value can be one of the following:
#- `NONE`: no client authentication is required.
#- `REQUEST`: authentication is requested but not required.
#- `REQUIRED`: authentication is required.
quarkus.http.ssl.client-auth=REQUEST 

